# I have installed python 3.4 and attempted to use pip to manage packages but unfortunately i recieve this error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

Operating System:Windows 10

I installed python 3.4.when i ran

```
python -m endurepip,
```

it says that it is uptodate.

But when I run this ,

it returns

```
C:\Python34>pip install django
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

even when i run this command,

```
C:\Python34>python -m pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)
```

it displays pip.

Comment: Why are you trying to run "Requirement already up-to-date" as a command?

Comment: sorry,I wrongly copied that.

Comment: Try `python -m pip install django`

Comment: python.exe -m pip install django worked for me

Comment: You could also try adding `pip` to your system path. It is in the `Scripts` directory.

Comment: Thank you saqibns,will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call `C:\Python34>pip install django` from CMD without python.exe

CMD has no idea what `pip` is.

You have to specify python exe as: (This works for me)

```
C:\Python34>python.exe -m pip install django
```

Or if python.exe is system var:

```
python -m pip install django
```